# CentOS: Using GCC 4.7 from devtoolset results in linking libstdc++ incorrectly (undefined symbols)

Tags: gcc, centos, undefined-symbol, devtoolset

I am using the devtoolset-1.0 for CentOS 6.3 in order to upgrade temporarily the GCC version. Although I am now able to compile my C++ application, the final binary is missing some symbols:

```
$ ldd -d -r myapp
$     [..]
$     libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003216e00000)
$     [..]
$ undefined symbol: _ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base11_M_transferEPS0_S1_    (./myapp)
$ undefined symbol: _ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_      (./myapp)
$ undefined symbol: _ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base9_M_unhookEv (./myapp)
```

I figured out, that these are some new functions, which aren't found in the 'old' libstdc++, but in a newer libstdc++. On my system, both libstdc++ (default version 4.4.7) and devtoolset-1.0-libstdc++-devel (4.7 via devtoolset) are installed. Interestingly, the libstdc++ from devtoolset links agains to the old one:

```
$ cat /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.0/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.0/libstdc++.so
$ /* GNU ld script
$    Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
$    the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
$ OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
$ INPUT ( /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -lstdc++_nonshared )
```

What I actually want is to replace the libstdc++ binding, but I don't know how to achieve that. I already tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and pointing to the devtoolset directory, but the libstdc++ was still set to the old location. Also a symbolic link did not result in a success, because it is a ld script and not actual shared library.

Comment: did you ever find a resolution to this problem?  Also, I'm curious if you have different missing symbols in debug vs. release builds, which is something I have observed as well.

Answer (score 2):

> the final binary is missing some symbols

That looks like a bug in `devtoolset-1-gcc`, which I assume has been fixed in more recent versions of devtoolset.

> Interestingly, the libstdc++ from devtoolset links agains to the old one:

Yes, that's how the devtoolset gcc is supposed to work (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52611144/981959) for more details).

> What I actually want is to replace the libstdc++ binding, but I don't know how to achieve that.

You can't do that with the devtoolset of GCC, because it doesn't even have a new `libstdc++.so` library. As you found, that file is actually a linker script, which links your binary to `libstdc++_nonshared.a /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so`

Since there is no new `libstdc++.so` you can't link to it.

Answer (score 1):

The GCC compiler and its libraries (very specially `g++` and corresponding `libstdc++` runtime) need to match. Compiling with a newer compiler **will** (very often, practically guaranteed if a new version of the language is supported) give binaries that don't work with an older library. Older binaries *might* work with a newer library, no guarantees here.

Comment: That's true in general, but is not relevant here as the question is about devtoolset which uses a special linkage model to avoid that problem.