# Segmentation fault when comparing std::system_error::code() and std::errc::invalid_argument

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I needed to check the error code of `std::system_error` doing my project.
But when I did that, I ended up with `SIGSEGV`.

`foo.cpp` :

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

int main(void)
{
    std::thread t1;

    try
    {
        t1.join();
    }
    catch (const std::system_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "System error\n";

        if (e.code() == std::errc::invalid_argument) // here in the operator==(), running into SIGSEGV 
        {
            std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: foo

SRCS := $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

foo: $(OBJS)
        gcc -o $@ $^ -lstdc++ -lpthread

%.o: %.cpp
        gcc -std=c++17 -Wall -c -g -O0 -pthread -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm -rf foo *.o
```

My gcc version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.2.1 20170829 (Red Hat 7.2.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I was posting this question, StackOverflow suggested similar questions. One of them is [How to portably compare std::system_error exceptions to std::errc values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405394/how-to-portably-compare-stdsystem-error-exceptions-to-stderrc-values). What is described in it seemed to be closely related to the problem I am going through. So I tested against gcc 8.3 which was in the list of problem fixed gcc versions.

> Fixed on all active branches, so will be fixed in the 6.5, 7.4, 8.3
>   and 9.1 releases.

But it still appeared to have not been fixed, or it is just another problem:

```sh
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ make
gcc -std=c++17 -Wall -c -g -O0 -pthread -o foo.o foo.cpp
gcc -o foo foo.o -lstdc++ -lpthread

$ ./foo
System error
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any ideas to work around this problem and detect which error actually it is when the `system_error` occurs?

---

Edit: Adding backtrace information with gdb

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000003603269ca2 in std::error_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000003603269ca2 in std::error_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x000000000040285f in std::operator== (__lhs=..., __rhs=...) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:299
#2  0x0000000000402628 in main () at foo.cpp:17
```

Comment: Since you are interested in detecting what the error is, why are you conditionally checking `e.what()` instead of outputting that before the `if`? (Maybe something like `std::cout << "System error: '" << e.what() << "'\n";`.)

Comment: Can you provide a backtrace? That would also answer the question whether it's the comparison or the call to `e.code()` that causes the segfault. Also, you could help yourself if you turned on diagnostics of the runtime library, which catches and reports a few cases of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh, there's one thing you may be doing wrong: You're using `gcc` to compile and link. Use `g++` instead. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34662c9678a39e10 suggests it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It has nothing to do with the command I used. No matter if it's gcc or g++, the gnu compiler collection will correctly invoke appropriate compiler/linker. As far as I know, "gcc" is only a facet that invokes preprocessor, compiler or linker. And I actually tried to check if using `g++` instead of `gcc` makes the program not crash, which turns out that it still crashes. And as I showed the stack trace, it crashes in the middle of `operator==` which continues  to call `std::error_category::equivalent`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I checked out your link that show it works. May be it's the gcc version, I guess. Anyway, I have decided to not print out any information about the error by removing the `if()` statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the difference between the gcc toolchain version that I used and the version by which the libstdc++ is built is the culprit.

[C++ project compiled with modern compiler, but linked against outdated libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609269/c-project-compiled-with-modern-compiler-but-linked-against-outdated-libstdc)

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91876

As to http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34662c9678a39e10 which shows a result that does not crash, I guess it had no problem because the library and the compiler versions match.